# Saving data using Local Storage

Tags: html, local-storage

I have been reading up about html `localStorage` but I've read contradicting information. All I would like to know is if I was to save information using `localStorage` was the user of that computer be the only person able to access/view the information that they had inputted into a form? Or can it also be viewed by users on different devices?

I am thinking to use local storage in an admin page that many people are allowed to access too, instead of sessions. And all users must be able to edit and view information from different devices and using different login details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `localStorage` is called like that because it can be accessed *only locally*. So you cannot use it to share the data across different clients. You need to use some server to store the data and provide it to your users.

Comment: Thank you. That just confirmed what i thought

Answer (score 1):

The `localStorage` object stores data on the users computer permanently, and that data can only be accesses on the users computer by the same origin or domain name, so if you want shared data you have to use some sort of server side mechanism.